# Iterating through file for API call not working

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe

I am attempting to iterate through a text file with corporation names and checking them against an api call and I am running into a problem. When I have one item in a line on the text file the code below works perfectly. If I have more than one it the "testing2" variable is null for every line except the last one. I don't know what is wrong with how I am iterating over this file.

See below:

```
with open('result') as f:
    for line in f:
        totalFoundInSource = totalFoundInSource + 1


if totalFoundInSource >0:
    client = Socrata("data.ny.gov", x)

    results = client.get(y, limit=2800000)

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)

    pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)

    lineNo = 0
    sys.stdout = open('result8', 'a')
    with open('result') as f:
        for line in f:
            
            testing2 = df[df['current_entity_name'].str.contains(line)]
            

            if not testing2.empty:
                if testing2['chairman_name'].isnull().values.any():
                    pass

                else:
                    print("/name/" +testing2[['chairman_name']].to_string(index = False, header= False).strip().replace(" ","-") + "_" + testing2[['dos_process_city']].to_string(index= False, header = False).strip().replace(" ","-") + "-NY")

                if testing2['registered_agent_name'].isnull().values.any():
                    pass

                else:
                    print("/name/" +testing2[['registered_agent_name']].to_string(index = False, header= False).strip().replace(" ","-") + "_" + testing2[['dos_process_city']].to_string(index= False, header = False).strip().replace(" ","-") + "-NY")

                if testing2['dos_process_name'].isnull().values.any():
                    pass
                else:
                    print("/name/" + testing2[['dos_process_name']].to_string(index=False,header=False).strip().replace(" ","-") + "_" +testing2[['dos_process_city']].to_string(index=False, header=False).strip().replace(" ","-") + "-NY")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I made another variable called line2 and made it equal to line.rstrip() after the "for line in f:" and then checked the dataframe against that line2 variable. It was counting the whitespace after the lines that were not last and this was causing the dataframe to return null.